# How to structure Libraries in Elm?

Tags: elm

I am in the process of tidying up some Elm code and I was wondering how to do the following:

Suppose I have the following File Structure

```
Project
|
|---Car
    |
    |--- BMW.elm
    |
    |--- Mercedes.elm

|...
```

Suppose that I have divided up the BMW and Mercedes code into different files in order to keep my code small and seperate and so it's much easier for me to just add another file, say `Toyota.elm`

Now, I would like for any files inside the Project folder to just access all the files in the `Car` folder without having to write

```
import Car.BMW (..)
import Car.Mercedes (..)
...etc...
```

Ideally, I'd like to just write something like

```
import Car (..)
```

and that just gives me access to everything inside each of these files.

Is it possible? If so, what is the best strategy to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elm doesn't support re-exporting modules so it isn't possible to create a single module which exports a handful of others which you can use to qualify functions. Assuming that you have distinct function names, you *could* do something like this:

```
module Utils where
import Foo
import Bar

foo = Foo.foo
bar = Bar.bar
```

Then you can do

```
module Other where
import Utils (..)

baz = foo 1 2 3

gak = bar 2 3
```

But you won't be able to get the fully qualified name to export from the Utils module.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot but that seems like a lot of trouble. I guess it's much easier to just have a cascade of import statements. :(

Comment: I think the idea is that re exporting modules makes it difficult to figure out where things are coming from when looking at code. Also, a good editor should be able to automagically manage your imports for you.

Comment: Is there an editor that supports automagically managing imports in Elm?

Comment: I have only used [elm-mode](https://github.com/jcollard/elm-mode) which doesn't currently support this.